# Hibernate 2nd level cache, Get all the child collections cache associated with a particular entity cache

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, second-level-cache

I am exposing a cache Eviction Method through JMX wherein I will pass in the key to the parent entity region and the method should clear the entire tree of caches associated with the parent, 
**Need to figure out how to get all the child collection cache regions and the child entity cache regions for a particular cached parent entity.**

Comment: Any particular cache provider? Or your own custom one?

Comment: I'm using HazelCast as a provider for the Hibernate 2nd level cache